# Dynamically creating Table Rows for a table

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to populate a highscores table for my game from data stored on the device's SD card.

Here is my `LeaderboardActivity.java`:

```
public class LeaderboardActivity extends Activity {
private Leaderboard leaderboard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

    TableLayout highscoresTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.highscoresTable);
    this.leaderboard = new Leaderboard();

    ArrayList<Player> players = leaderboard.getScores();
    if(!(players==null))
    {
        Collections.sort(players);

        for(Player p:players)
        {
            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
            TextView name = new TextView(this);
            TextView time = new TextView(this);

            name.setText(p.getName());
            name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            name.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
            time.setText(p.getTime());
            time.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            time.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);

            newRow.addView(name);
            newRow.addView(time);
            highscoresTable.addView(newRow);
        }
        setContentView(highscoresTable);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "players is equal to null!");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_leaderboard, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my XML `activity_leaderboard.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/highscoresTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/headerRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:text="NAME"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="TIME" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/testRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:text="TEST"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="NOT REAL" />

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason when I run my leaderboard it causes a `RuntimeException`

How can I get this working?

---

#### UPDATE

As requested, here's my log:

```
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*.*.*.*/*.*.*.*.LeaderboardActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x77
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x77
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at *.*.*.*.LeaderboardActivity.onCreate(LeaderboardActivity.java:44)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-29 13:45:41.136: E/AndroidRuntime(9894):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is there any reason for setting the content view **again** after that for loop? Also, **always** mention **what** does the exception says(and of course post the stacktrace).

Comment: Here's my log: http://pastebin.com/euEWtezZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `p.getTime()` method returns an `int`. Using this `int` value with `setText()` will make the `TextView` think you're setting the text using an id referring a `string` resource which most likely isn't the case. Instead use:

```
time.setText(String.valueOf(p.getTime()));
```

Comment: I've just done this and now I have an `IllegalStateException` instead... so it still crashes. Here's my new log: http://pastebin.com/evueGVXB

Comment: @Jamesking56 As I said in the comment, remove the line `setContentView(highscoresTable);`. You add the items to the already present table, there is no reason for setting the content to the same table.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! I thought I'd have to set it again to 'refresh' the table to show the data. I'm new to Android development so thanks for giving me a hand. :)